How can I remove edges of a Graph faster?
I have a graph
GraphData[{"Antiprism", 6}]


I remove polygon $ABCDEF$ like this

I tried
g = GraphData[{"Antiprism", 6}]
edgesToRemove = {UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], 
   UndirectedEdge[3, 4], UndirectedEdge[4, 5], UndirectedEdge[5, 6], 
   UndirectedEdge[6, 1]};
newGraph = EdgeDelete[g, edgesToRemove]


How can I revome edges of a Graph faster? Can I general with  GraphData[{"Antiprism", n}]?

Removing edges is blindingly fast!  $0.000749$ seconds.  It just takes time to load your particular (named) graph.  It wouldn't take time with a hand-crafted graph.

maybe GraphDifference[g, CycleGraph[VertexCount[g]/2], Options[g]]?

Like this?
n = 6;
g = GraphData[{"Antiprism", n}]
edgesToRemove = Table[UndirectedEdge[i, Mod[i, n] + 1], {i, 1, n}];
newGraph = EdgeDelete[g, edgesToRemove]


